# StyleSheet work in Design View but NOT when running the website

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

im having a problem when add the link to the StyleSheet in my XHTML code and click con Design View. The linked CSS work correctly and do the respective changes, but when i run the website it doesnt show any chance.

My code in XHTML:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/LoginCss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div id="divGrande">
        <table cellspacing="10px" cellpadding="10px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellspacing="2px" cellpadding="2px">
```

Comment: Check your developer tools in the browser, the path is probably wrong. Try removing the `~`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with XHTML, but do you have to have the ~ before /Styles/LoginCss.css? Why can't you just use create a relative URL structure from the Root folder?

```
<link href="/Styles/LoginCss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```